# Changing the order of pinned Folders in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-quick-access

Was looking at answers to this question but was unable to answer. So, I will post what I have done and would like to know if it worked for you.

On Windows 10 in File Explorer window: I was able to move folders pinned in Quick Access above the Documents library. I ordered them the way I wanted. When I was done, I moved the Documents library back above the reordered folders and the order once again was locked down.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.